# CanvasSpriteBatch, Begin / End methods to draw a lot of sprites with the same SpriteBatch

Tags: c#, win2d

I coded a simple class to manage the drawing of a bitmap.

Is this a good way to implement `Begin()` - `End()` methods to draw multiple sprites from different objects (As in XNA's omonime methods)?

```cs
public class Caravaggio : IDrawingService
{
    private CanvasDrawingSession _ds = null;
    private CanvasSpriteBatch _sb = null;

    private CanvasImageInterpolation _interpolation = CanvasImageInterpolation.Linear;
    private CanvasSpriteOptions _options = CanvasSpriteOptions.ClampToSourceRect;
    private CanvasSpriteSortMode _sortMode = CanvasSpriteSortMode.None;

    public bool EnableDebugDrawing { get; set; } = false;

    // This is being set from outside each CanvasAnimatedControl Draw event.
    // I made this because I'd like to pass only a "Caravaggio" parameter to my draw functions.
    public void SetDrawingEntity(CanvasDrawingSession DrawingEntity)
    {
        _ds = DrawingEntity;
    }

    public void Begin()
    {
        _sb = _ds.CreateSpriteBatch(_sortMode, _interpolation, _options);
    }

    public void End()
    {
        _sb.Dispose();
        _sb = null;
    }

    public void DrawBitmap(
        CanvasBitmap Bitmap,
        Rect SourceRect,
        Vector2 Position,
        Color OverlayColor,
        Vector2 Origin,
        float Rotation,
        Vector2 Scale,
        bool FlipHorizontally)
    {
        if (_ds == null)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("CanvasDrawingSession not set");
        }

        if (_sb == null)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("CanvasSpriteBatch not set. Did you forget to call Begin()?");
        }

        _sb.DrawFromSpriteSheet(
            Bitmap,
            Position, SourceRect,
            ColorToVector4(OverlayColor),
            Origin, Rotation, Scale,
            FlipHorizontally ? CanvasSpriteFlip.Horizontal : CanvasSpriteFlip.None);

        if (EnableDebugDrawing)
        {
            _ds.DrawRectangle(Position.X, Position.Y, (float)SourceRect.Width, (float)SourceRect.Height, Colors.Red);
        }
    }
```

I know this is very simple, but it's just for "hobby" purposes.

I think this methods are an improvement if you don't want to create a new SpriteBatch object for every drawn entity, like when you draw your objects in this way:

```
// GameManager
public void Draw(IDrawingService MyDrawingService)
{
    MyDrawingService.Begin();

    _background.Draw(MyDrawingService);    

    foreach (Player p in _players)
       p.Draw(MyDrawingService);

    _score.Draw(MyDrawingService);

    MyDrawingService.End();
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but anyway:  It's not clear to me what value this is adding on top of the normal CanvasSpriteBatch API.  Perhaps showing how this improves the calling code would provide enough context to help answer the "is this a good way to..." question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a reasonable way to start building abstractions on top of Win2D.

Where you have Begin/End pairs I'd usually like to see something that's IDisposable, so you can use it with "using".  Something like:

```
public void Draw(IDrawingService MyDrawingService)
{
    using (var session = MyDrawingService.Begin())
    {

        _background.Draw(session);    

        ...
    }
}
```

This sort of thing allows you to easily return or throw an exception from within a Begin/End pair without worrying about missing the End.

Answer (score 1):

I think its a good starting point.

I can see more advantages if you wrap more Win2D stuffs, lets say instead of using the CanvasBitmap you use your own Sprite entity.
Another thing you can also add is the ability to create multiple Sprite Batches, instead of using a single one.

I am about to do something similar for a small project, I will update my version when it's done.